# How to prevent multiple clicks - trigger clicks - on page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, eventtrigger

I have this case - need to trigger some click after scroll to specify page height. But i need to do this only one time, insead of this i have multiple tiggers. I guess this happens by scrolling. I've try to do this with `one()` method but it's still not working... This is the code:

```
var viewport = $(document);

viewport.on({
    scroll: function() {
        var scrolled = viewport.scrollTop();

            switch (true) {
                case scrolled > 2800:
                    $('.js-event_003').one(function(){
                       $(this).trigger('click');
                    });
                    break;
                case scrolled > 2000:
                    $('.js-event_002').one(function(){
                        $(this).trigger('click');
                    });
                    break;
                case scrolled > 600:
                    $('.js-event_001').one(function(){
                        $(this).trigger('click');
                    });
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Can anybody help? Thx!

Comment: you register the click event each time scroll got triggered? try to deregister the event first using `off()`

Comment: `one` takes event(s) as first parameter http://api.jquery.com/one/ if you want to `trigger click` why `bind` any event. All you need is a map or variable to track which click where triggered so it's done only once.

Comment: can u show me how to do this?